# angular js injector module error while using 'angularFileUpload'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

Am using AngularJS v1.6.4 for my node app
later i hv installed angular-file-upload from npm
when ever i add angular.module name 'angularFileUpload' it get's ( master.js:26 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] )
master.js is collection of js (jquery,angular,slimscroll,toaster etc..);

```
var LifeApp = angular.module('LifeApp',['ui.router','ngRoute','ui.grid','ui.grid.selection','angularFileUpload']);
```

once i start the node app `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you required/imported the module? Installing a package only adds it to the node_modules folder, after that you need to require it inside your application like `require("angular-file-upload");`.